# how to allow users to write queries without being executed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

well im making a blog that is almost done.. i wana allow users to post questions where they can post a query as there comment without allowing this query to be actually executed ..  i tried making some security  .. i used mysql_real_escape_string, htmlentities(), htmlspecialchars(), strip_tags() and addslashes()
.. however when i write something like
SELECT * FROM TABLE an error occurs disallowing me from posting the comment

im inserting the comments using this query

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO comments (topic_id,commenters_id,comment,media,mediaType) VALUES ("' . $topic_id . '", "' . $commenter_id . '", "' . $comment . '", "' . $media . '", "' . $mediaType . '")';
```

Comment: Well if a user posts an SQL query, the only way that query could actually be run is **if you run it**. So I dont see the issue, **just dont run it**!! Am I missing something

Comment: The question title kind of makes it sound like you're trying to figure out how to stop killing all your users.

Comment: But really, the way to prevent this from happening is to use prepared statements instead of concatenating user input into your SQL.

Comment: So users query "SELECT * FROM TABLE" is stored in $comment variable?

Comment: @Faraz that was just an example .. everything went fine when i used prepared statements as suggested .. i'm new to php that's all.. i wanted them to be able to post what ever they wana post including  queries ..
when i was testing .. appeared to me that random queries make errors and intended queries was being executed .. i wanted to prevent it thats all

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to insert a comment containing SQL without it being executed. The reason you are having trouble is that you are concatenating user input into your SQL string. If you use prepared statements and bind the user input as parameters instead, you won't have this problem.Here is an example of how to do that (adapted from the PHP [quickstart guide on mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)).

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO comments 
           (topic_id,commenters_id,comment,media,mediaType) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

// prepare
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

// bind parameters (I'm not sure if I picked the correct types here)
if (!$stmt->bind_param("iisss", $topic_id, $commenter_id, $comment, $media, $mediaType)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

// execute
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```